# Converting dates into minutes in R + Error in as.POSIXlt.character message

Tags: r, date, parse-error, posixlt

I am pretty new to R.
I have a variable with a date and hour automatically created by the survey platform (Qualtrics) named enddate. I would like to convert that variable into minutes from midnight (the dates are shown in this format: `08/03/2020 08:17`).

I tried this code I found around the web:

```
enddate _mins＜- hour(dat$enddate) * 60 + minute(dat$enddate) / 60
```

but I get this error message:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz = tz(x)) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I searched about this error and I found the following code to solve the previous issue:

```
enddate_num <- parse_date_time(dat$enddate, orders = "mdy HM")
```

I am now getting this error:

```
Warning message: 1306 failed to parse
```

I would very much appreciate your help as I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: It is possible that you may have more than one format.  Can you do `library(parsedate);enddate_num <- parse_date(dat$enddate)`

Comment: It seems it omit many cases. This is the message i get reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 2659 entries

Comment: please consider to provide a reproducible example that shows the issue

Answer (score 0):

There is a `difftime()` function.

Covert the string to a datetime and then use the function:

```
timestring <-"08/03/2020 08:17" 

difftime(as.POSIXct(timestring, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz="GMT"), 
         as.POSIXct(timestring, "%d/%m/%Y", tz="GMT"), 
         units="mins")
```

Comment: Thank you, I am still getting many cases with NAs. For some reason, it does not convert the values of some specific observations.

Comment: @dandan The code above works for the provided sample case.  If you are still getting errors, then please elaborate and provides examples.  I can't help if I don't know what the problem is.